# Export an instance to external component with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants

I have a configuration component in react and I need to export the instance to another external component, in this case the:
**const appInstance**

```
export const setupApp = () => {
  if (isAppAvailable) {
    try {
      {...}

      const appConfiguration = new AppConfiguration(KEY);
      AppConfig.configure(appConfiguration);

      // I need to export this const
      const appInstance = AppConfig.start(startInstance);
      
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
};
```

And in other component, I need to take this instance, like this:

```
// get app instance from another page
appInstance.get(myTest)
  .then((value) => {
    if (...) {
      something
    } else {
      something;
    }
  });
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: you can provide is with a top level context provider

Comment: can you explain me better how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `setupApp` currently has no return value. If you add `appInstance` to the return, you can access it from outside the function.

```js
export const setupApp = () => {
  if (isAppAvailable) {
    try {
      {...}

      const appConfiguration = new AppConfiguration(APP_KEY);
      AppConfig.configure(appConfiguration);

      // I need to export this const
      const appInstance = AppConfig.start(startInstance);

      return {
          appConfiguration,
          appInstance,
      }
      
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
};
```

```js
// get app instance from another page
const appInstance = setupApp().appInstance
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I can't use the return, in es-lint this error occurs

-- Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function